# Symfony 3.4.4 + FOSUserBundle + Sonata Admin - Pretty login

Tags: authentication, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I'm starting with Symfony + Sonata Admin + FosUserbundle

Everything works perfectly. But my loguin screen is very ugly.

How can I automatically make the login be as "nice" as the SonataAdmin skin?

I do not understand why the rest of the SonataAdmin SI has nice styles and templates but the Login does not.

This is how my login looks
[image]

This is how my Admin looks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems no css/js is loaded ... can you check the html source view of your login page? Check especially the css includes, they should point to a resource of your public web folder. If you click the link, you should see the css file in your browser.
If the resource not exist, execute the install:assets command (again).
If the css exist, try to clear your browser and symfony cache and reload the page.